# Comparing probability and dimension forumulas, concidence?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory

So we know that if given two finite vector spaces $V,W$ then the $\dim(V+ W)=\dim(V)+\dim(W)-\dim(V\cap W)$ This curiously corresponds with the Probability formula of, given two probabilities $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$

Question, is this a mere coincidence or is there something deeper going on? Probabilities are always numbers between 0 and 1, the dimension of a vector space is, I assume, always a natural number. So anything special going on?

Comment: I wonder what it is that you call the dimension of $V\cup W$.

Comment: Perhaps what's going on is that for any measure $\mu$ you get this equation, and dimension is a sort of counting measure on vector spaces.

Comment: @did, remind me to look for hidden meanings in your comments in the future.

Comment: Both the collections $\mathcal F$ of subspaces of a vector space, with the operations of $+,\cap$, and the sigma-algebra $\mathcal S$ of a probability space with the "operations" $\cup,\cap$ have an algebraic structure, and the "homomorphisms" $\dim:\mathcal F\to \Bbb R_+$ and $\mathrm{Prob}\colon\mathcal S\to\Bbb R_+$ respect that structure in a certain way. It may be possible to expand on this half-baked observation to make a theory that produces some of these "coincidences."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WARNING:** This does not work for sums of more than two subspaces.

$$
\dim(U+V+W)
$$
may differ from
$$
\dim U+\dim V+\dim W-\dim(U\cap V)-\dim(U\cap W)-\dim(V\cap W)+\dim(U\cap V\cap W).
$$
For example, it doesn't work if $U,V,W$ are distinct one-dimensional subspaces of a two-dimensional space.

Answer (score 1):

This is a consequence of the **additivity** property, both of the dimension of a subspace and of probability, as Gerry commented, they both are some kind of *measures*.

If $U,V$ are 'disjoint' subspaces (i.e. $U\cap V=\{0\}$), then $\dim(U+V)=\dim U+\dim V$.

If $A,B$ are disjoint 'events' (subsets of the probability space), then $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$.

This is the basic rule for area/volume, and any measure. There are also [Projection valued measures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection-valued_measure), which can be used for some kind of probability using (projections to) subspaces of a Hilbert space..

Comment: I think this point of view may mislead people into thinking that this works for more than two subspaces, i.e. that in general the dimension of the sum of three subspaces is $\dim U+\dim V+\dim W-\dim(U\cap V)-\dim(U\cap W)-\dim(V\cap W)+\dim(U\cap V\cap W)$.  But that is false.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for the [Inclusion–exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).